# Question about maximal ideals in a commutative Artinian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm currently going through the section in Dummit and Foote regarding the structure of commutative artinian rings with unity. It has already shown that there exists finitely many distinct maximal ideals $M_1,\ldots,M_n$. It then defines $Jac(R)=M_1 \cap M_2 \cap \cdots \cap M_n$, and the following statement is given:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^n M_i^m \subseteq \left( \prod_{i=1}^n M_i \right)^m \subseteq Jac(R)^m$$

My question is, why does the book say "$\subseteq$" and not "="? Aren't these ideals all equal? The first equality follows from the fact that ideal multiplication is commutative, and the second follows from the fact that any two distinct maximal ideals must be coprime, so $M_1M_2\cdots M_n=M_1\cap M_2\cap\cdots\cap M_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is correct, but overlooks the role of this statement in the argument being made.  The goal is to prove that $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i^m=0$ for a certain value of $m$, and so this is proved by observing that $$\prod_{i=1}^n M_i^m \subseteq \left( \prod_{i=1}^n M_i \right)^m \subseteq Jac(R)^m$$ and that $Jac(R)^m=0$ for this value of $m$.  The other directions of the inclusions are true, but are not needed for the conclusion that $\prod_{i=1}^n M_i^m=0$ and so are not stated.  (Though, I agree it is fairly silly to write $\subseteq$ for this first inclusion since it is very obviously an equality.)